# Array Help row of a sum

Tags: java

The problem I'm having with my code is, trying to figure out how to get the sum of a single row in an array and print out each sum of each row.

I can't get the sum of a single row, it just gives the output of sums, which is 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumEle {

    public static double[][] sums() {
        double[][] x = new double[4][3];
        double  p;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the 3 by 4 matrix: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length;i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++)
                x[i][j] = input.nextDouble();

        return x;
    }

    public static void result(double[][] x) {
        double total = 0;
        double[] rowSum = new double[x.length];
        for(int column = 0; column< x.length; column++) {
            rowSum[column] = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i <x[column].length;i++) {
                total = total + x[column][i];
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] x = sums();
        result(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are declaring `rowSum` but you are summing up using `total` variable.

Comment: There are some obvious problems here.  (By "obvious" I mean it's obviously homework and you need to make more effort yourself.) You should try working the problem by hand and looking at each step.  As a hint, look at how many results you get when you do it by hand, then look at how many results (just one) you actually print.

Comment: Just moved the variable double total = 0; to inside the for(int column = 0; column< x.length; column++){ double total = 0; .... } and it is printing all values

Comment: To make your code easier to understand, you should follow common naming guidelines. Your method names should be verbs if they _do_ something, and nouns if they are functions (they _return_ something). Your `sums()` method doesn't return sums. It should instead be called something like `inputValues()`. And `result` doesn't return a result. It should be called something like `printSums`.

Comment: This is a similar question with a verified answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486521/java-array-sum-of-specific-row